# Visual Studio C++ Solution compilation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio Solution contains the following projects :

```
Solution
 -> FolderName
      C++ Project Name 1 
      C++ Project Name 2
 -> C++ Project Name 3 
 -> C# Project Name
```

`C++ Project Name 3` is a library type project (generates a dll and a lib)

`C++ Project Name 1 and 2` use a header from `C++ Project Name 3` and in the linker section they expect for the lib generated by `C++ Project Name 3`

If compiled one by one in the project order (3,1,2) everything is compiled correctly and works, but in case i try to compile the entire solution i get a linker error stating that it cannot compile `C++ project Name 1` because it cannot find the lib from `C++ Project Name 3` .

My question is how can i compile correctly (in the expected order) if i select compile solution ? Next step i have to do is to compile using the build system from TFS and i expect there i will have the same problem

Comment: Project -> Project Build Order...? Or maybe set `C++ Project Name 3` as Project Dependency of `C++ Project Name 1`?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to set the project 3 as a dependency of projects 1 and 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to the `Project` menu, then `Project Dependencies`. Select the project that "needs" the library, and check the library's check box. This will tell Visual Studio how to determine order or compilation.

Note: you can also manually change build order, but by setting dependencies, Visual Studio can work out the order itself, which may be more optimal.

[MSDN: How to: Create and Remove Project Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to set up your project dependencies for the solution. [How to: Create and Remove Project Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Project Dependencies, Common Properties, Solution Property Pages Dialog Box to set the current build order. To access this dialog box, select a solution in Solution Explorer, choose Property Pages on the View menu, and then select Project Dependencies under Common Properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk4ahe0t(v=vs.90).aspx